# Перевод пункта при навигации клавиатурой

Tags: обсуждение, дефект, локализация

Если вызвать подсказку для навигации с помощью клавиатуры, нажав на кнопк `G`, то во втором пунтке неправильно написан текст. Должно быть `вопросы`,  а не `вопросов`

А вообще, если глобально по этой подсказке, то я ещё правильно написал бы падежи у всех пунктов

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Падежи я бы не трогал.

Comment: @Qwertiy Ну как-то странно читается "перейти метки", пототму и предложил :)

Comment: Ну "перейти" - это скорее заголовок. А дальше как оглавление - в именительном падеже.

Comment: @Qwertiy Тогда можно убрать многоточие и поставить двоеточие. Просто на английском это звучит "go to home page", "go to tags" и т.д., а русский чуть более сложный, чтобы так просто переводить отдельные куски :)

Comment: Можно и двоеточие)